# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BOWImgDescriptorExtractor' in Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Getting very confused. Searched around but could not find any help that was useful. I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main_test.py", line 105, in
>   
>       train(descriptors,image_classes,image_paths)   File "main_test.py", line 40, in train
>       bow_extract  = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(descr_ext,matcher) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'BOWImgDescriptorExtractor'

I was following this link code:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/machine-learning-image-detectioncats-vs-dogs-amrith-kumar
But i am not able to implement it and getting above error.

```
def train(descriptors,image_classes,image_paths):
  flann_params = dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 5)    
  matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
  bow_extract  = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(descr_ext,matcher)
  bow_train = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also install opencv-contrib-python. See the package on [pip](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/).

To install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```